# Loading a Custom Server Control on the fly

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(@"CustomControls.Nav.dll");
 //Namespace and assembly name are CustomControls.Nav , the class name for the control is WebBar
Type type = assembly.GetType("CustomControls.Nav.WebBar");
```

I am getting type as null.What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Stupid questions I know, but is assembly returning null.  Does that dll contain that type? Can you view it through the Object Viewer.

Comment: I can see the assembly in debugger that it is not null but the next line assembly.GetType("") returns null

Comment: Are you spelling the name of the type correctly?

Comment: And is the type public? Please show exactly how the WebBar type is defined in its original source code.

Answer (score 0):

What does Object Browser display when you look at this Assembly?  Is it showing CustomControls.Nav.WebBar?